# How to fix Xcode cloud build issues generated for third party libraries added through SPM?

Tags: ios, swift, cicd, swift-package-manager, xcode-cloud

I'm deploying my app using Xcode Cloud. I'm using SPM for libraries & I'm getting this issue (as screenshot attached) in the Xcode cloud. My build has succeeded in the code but is failing in the Xcode cloud.

Please help me to out this issue.

[image: Xcode Cloud SPM errors]

Comment: Im facing the exact same issue. All of a sudden XCode cloud is not working. 
Even when compiling old code (that was deployed through XCode cloud), I get the same errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check: Xcode cloud might be building with a preview or a release candidate version.

In XCode cloud:

- Select your app
- Select "Manage Workflows".
- Select a workflow
- Change Xcode version to a stable version (currently Xcode 15.2)

This solved the issue for me

Comment: My archive is succeed but I'm still getting another issue in the testing. Asynchronous wait failed: Exceeded timeout of 120 seconds, with unfulfilled expectations. Help me if you have the same issue.